# How to get multiline input with empty lines - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I can get Multiline input with this loop but it stops as soon there is an empty line

```
    lines = []
    line = input()
    while True:
        if line:
            line = input()
            lines.append(line)

        else:
            return lines
            break
```

For example how could i get an input of

```
1 cup butter, melted
3 cups white sugar
1 tablespoon vanilla extract
4 eggs


1 1/2 cups all-purpose flour
1 cup unsweetened cocoa powder
1 teaspoon salt
1 cup semisweet chocolate chips
```

Comment: are you trying to use `raw_input()` method?

Comment: And when should your program stop? At what condition?

Comment: As soon as it has all the input

Comment: @HarryTong How does you program know that it has done taking the input? Because as per your requirement, your program should run whenever there will be a empty string

Comment: you need something like `while line != 'done'` and then type 'done' when you're finished

Comment: `break` after `return` is pointless btw

Comment: @Chris_Rands is there anyway i can do this without making the user type something at the end

Comment: how is the "the end" defined? you need some condition, or else read it from a file and just iterate over the lines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use something to mark the end of the input.
Right now your code stops on empty lines. Because `line` is going to get the blank value '' that evaluates to False. So your iteration breaks.
You could use a mark. For example, `end_of_list;`:

```
lines = []
line = input()
while True:
    if line != 'end_of_list;': 
        line = input()
        lines.append(line)

    else:
        return lines
        break
```

You could also add some more condition to avoid appending blank values. It depends of your goals.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without making the user put the mark?

Comment: You could count the number of line breaks. For example, two or three breaks to mark the end.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because 
    if line = "" (Empty text)

your  IF LINE:    assert it to False and you return  lines and break

So try to change you if

```
if line or line == "":
```

Comment: `if line or line == "":`? So `if True:`?

Comment: But I can't think of a way to make it stop once it has everything

Comment: Use custom end string like '!!' (whatever you want) and if line is not equal to  custom end string -Do your code- ELSE - BREAK it